# Why don't blocking and non-blocking assignments behave the same in a testbench?

Tags: verilog, test-bench

I write a D flip-flop module as below:

```
module mod1(
    input clk,
    input d,
    output reg q
);

    always @(posedge clk)begin
        q <= d;
    end

endmodule
```

These are the two code snippets I used to test my module `mod1`

```
// code 1
module mod1_tb;
    reg clk;
    reg d;
    wire q;
    
    mod1 dut(
        .clk(clk),
        .d(d),
        .q(q)
    );
    
    always #10 clk = ~clk;
    
    initial begin
        clk = 0;

        @(posedge clk)
            d <= 0;
        @(posedge clk)
            d <= 1;
        @(posedge clk)
            d <= 0;
        @(posedge clk)
            d <= 1;
    
    end

endmodule
```

The waveform can be seen like this:
[image: waveform1]

```
// code 2
module mod1_tb;
    reg clk;
    reg d;
    wire q;
    
    mod1 dut(
        .clk(clk),
        .d(d),
        .q(q)
    );
    
    always #10 clk = ~clk;
    
    initial begin
        clk = 0;
        
        @(posedge clk);
        d = 0;
        @(posedge clk);
        d = 1;
        @(posedge clk);
        d = 0;
        @(posedge clk);
        d = 1;
    
    end

endmodule
```

The waveform can be seen like this:
[image: testbench2]

In my view, all of them should work well, but the result shows that only the first way works.
I am a little confused about why the second one does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The assumption is that your input signal (`d`) is synchronous to the clock. You should drive that signal in your testbench similarly to how it is driven in the design. Use `@(posedge clk)`, as you are already doing, and use nonblocking assignments (`<=`) instead of blocking (`=`).

Your `code 1` properly uses **nonblocking** in the testbench, which is why it simulates as you expect.

Your `code 2` uses **blocking** in the testbench, which is why it does not simulate as expected.

The nonblocking assignment guarantees that the simulator will sample the synchronous input at the time you expect it to.

The recommended good coding practice is to use nonblocking for sequential logic, such as flip-flops.

---

There is plenty of literature out there which discusses the details of Verilog event scheduling.  [Here is one paper.](http://www.sunburst-design.com/papers/CummingsSNUG2000SJ_NBA.pdf)